# Visualizing genus-two Riemann surfaces: from the three-fold branched cover to the sphere with two handles

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces, branched-covers

I am trying to visualize the genus-two Riemann surface given by the curve

$$
y^3 = \frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}{(x-x_3)(x-x_4)}.
$$

We can regard this surface as a three-fold cover of the sphere with four branch points. An image of the surface is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNa4D.png). Represented like this, it is not straightforward to me that this surface is topologically equivalent to a sphere with two handles. I am wondering if there is a way to deform this surface into something that resembles a double torus.

As an example, we can take the [following deformation of the torus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQn9P.png). In particular, I would like to map the non-contractible cycles of the genus-two surface from one picture to the other  (for the torus, two of these cycles are depicted in red and blue).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The picture (produced by Nick Schmitt) of the Lawson surface of genus 2 might help:  [image: the Lawson surface] It shows the genus 2 Riemann surface given by the algebraic equation $$y^3=\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}.$$ The lines show the vertical and horizontal trajectories of a holomorphic quadratic differential (given by a constant multiple of $\frac{(dz)^2}{z^4-1}$).
You can deform the surface by Moebius transformations in the [webgl applet][2] (also by Nick Schmitt; use 2 fingers to apply Moebius transformations) to the following biholomorphic Riemann surface: [![enter image description here][3]][3]

[2]: https://www.discretization.de/gallery/model/45)/
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aud2m.png

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: That link appears to be broken but [this page](https://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/user/nick/lawson/lawson.html) seems to be the same content.